# How to install Kinetic on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is it possible to install Kinetic on Ubuntu 14? The obvious `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-base` fails.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238763/how-to-install-kinetic-on-ubuntu-14?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Kinetic installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) clearly state that binary packages (`apt-get`) for ROS Kinetic are only available for Ubuntu Wily (15.10) and Xenial (16.04).

I'd recommend that you use [ROS Indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) instead (it is a long-term support release compatible with Ubuntu 14.04)

If you have a specific package that you need, you can try to build it from source on Indigo (usually works), or you can build [Kinetic from source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source), but the full source installation can take a while.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-07-04**:
Will a ROS node on a computer running Indigo be able to communicate to ROS nodes on a system running Kinetic?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-04**:
Probably. Perhaps if you asked about what you're actually trying to do instead of asking about a proposed solution without context, we could help you better. (See http://xyproblem.info/ )